How to capture RecordChange & RecordLoad Event in LWC?
So my requirement is when I Change the Opportunity Stage then I want to display popup message. In Aura, we have an option force:recordData which can be useful for this requirement.
Below is sample Aura Code:
cmp file:
<force:recordData aura:id="forceRecordDataCmp"
recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
layoutType="FULL"
targetRecord="{!v.record}"
targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
targetError="{!v.error}"
recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}" 
mode="VIEW" />

controller File:
recordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {
        var stageNameValues = component.get("v.stageNameValues");
        var eventParams = event.getParams();
        if(eventParams.changeType === "CHANGED") {
            var changedFields = eventParams.changedFields;
            if (eventParams.changedFields.StageName!=null && changedFields.StageName.oldValue != changedFields.StageName.value  
                && (stageNameValues.includes(changedFields.StageName.value))){ 
                // some logic
            }
        } else if(eventParams.changeType === "ERROR") {
            
        }
    }

In LWC, I have tried to refer documentation of notifyRecordUpdateAvailable
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/reference-notify-record-update.html
but it does not work when you use Standard layout to update the record. It works for  imperative Apex or by calling User Interface API via a third-party framework as per documentation.
In some articles, it has been mentioned that using getRecord, it would work so I created below LWC:
JS:
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const fields = ['Opportunity.StageName'];
export default class RecordChangeTest extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    record;
    error;
    Stage;
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data;
            let updatedStage = this.record.fields.StageName.value;
            if(!this.Stage){
                this.Stage = this.record.fields.StageName.value;
            }
            if (updatedStage !== this.Stage) {
                this.showMessage();
            }
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }
    showMessage(){
        //some logic
    }
}

with above LWC I tested below scneario:

When record loads first time then it does not call showMessage() method -- Expected Behavior
When I change the Stage then showMessage() gets called -- Expected behavior
When I change some other fields then showMessage() gets called -- showMessage() should not be called.

What I am doing wrong here?
I know we can use CDC but I dont want to go with that approach so looking for a way similar similar to force:recordData in Aura.
